# Converter String para Decimal preservando todos os números - PHP

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte exemplo de conversão:

```
$string = "2.016,24"
$int = (float)$string
```

O resultado do código acima é = 2.016
Porém preciso resgatar o número completo dess valor, sendo assim, preciso a string para um número completo como: 2.016,24

Comment: Você não vai poder ter `.` (ponto) como separador de milhar, e a `,` (vírgula) separadora das casas decimais tem que virar ponto, resultando em: `2016.24`, dá para fazer com `(float) str_replace(['.', ','], ['', '.'], '2.016,24')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que maneira mais correta de fazer isso é utilizando a `NumberFormatter`, disponível na extensão `intl` do PHP.

Como instalar a extensão intl, caso ainda não a tenha: https://www.dotkernel.com/php-troubleshooting/where-is-the-intl-php-extension-problem-solved/

Com isso a solução será bastante simples. Você primeiro deve criar uma `$format` indicando o locale:

```
$format = numfmt_create('pt_BR', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
```

e utilizá-la com sua variável que contém o valor em string que deseja converter. Então:

```
$converted = numfmt_parse($format, "2.016,24");
```

a variável converted terá o valor float que precisa. Exemplo do var_dump da variável:

```
var_dump($converted);

>> (float) 2016.24
```

### Exemplo completo:

```
$format = numfmt_create('pt_BR', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$converted = numfmt_parse($format, "2.016,24"); 
var_dump($converted);
>> (float) 2016.24
```

**Referências:**

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.numberformatter.php
https://www.dotkernel.com/php-troubleshooting/where-is-the-intl-php-extension-problem-solved/

Comment: Gostaria de entender os motivos da negativação da minha resposta. Uma vez que está correta e foi testada.